# Please add the `tagged` parameter to /answers, /users, etc

Tags: feature-request, tags, users, api-v2.2, answers

The `/questions` endpoint supports a `tagged` parameter which I find quite useful.  However, it's the only route that appears to support this parameter.

If, say, I want to get questions asked by a given user (with `/user/{ids}/questions`) I can't filter based on tags as well.

Additionally, `/answers` and `/user/{ids}/answers` endpoints don't support tag filtering.  (I understand that answers don't have tags, per se, but it's still would be quite helpful if I could filter this way)

Right now, when I want to filter questions by both user and tag, I have to dump all the questions or answers by a user, and then manually filter the tags.  This is kind of a time consuming process, and wastes a lot of API calls and bandwidth.

It's worse for answers though - first I have to dump all the answers by that user, and then ask for all the questions, and then discard all the answers on the questions that don't match the tag.

Dumping, say, all the answers posted within a given time period on a tag by anyone yields a similarly wasteful set of queries - I've got to filter answers by time period, then request questions, and then dump any data that wasn't tagged the way I want.

Can we get the "tagged" parameter on more endpoints?  Specifically I'd like it on the `/user/{ids}/*` endpoints which return questions or answers if possible, but any endpoint that returns question or answer objects would likely benefit.

Answer (score 2):

### Hear! Hear!

I want to study **what makes a good answer on SO**.
I started by querying complete web pages (questions with all comments, answers, and their comments) for questions with some minimum score (such as 5) for a number of fixed tags A,B,C created in some time period (say, one full week two months ago). This can be done well with `\search` and a filter that includes answers and comments along with the questions.

I tried predicting the score from some attributes and this worked much better for the answers than for the questions.

As it also is the answers I am interested in primarily, not the questions, it is wasteful to obtain those answers only via questions, because I have to throw away most of what I retrieve to fit my query parameters (min score, not to speak of the intended creation time frame...).

**I really need the `tagged=` parameter on the `\answers` endpoint** (or the `\posts` endpoint).

But trying to imagine what the implementation looks like I guess that is not likely to appear any time soon??