# Search for answers/comments under questions with certain tags using the Stack Overflow API?

Tags: support, api, tags, api-v2.2, answers

[The advanced search (`/search/advanced`) API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) can search for questions by tags.

But [`/users/{ids}/answers`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers) API doesn't take tags.

I'd like to monitor answers/comments for questions with certain tags. Is there an API which can search for answers/comments under questions with certain tags?

If not, I'll have to use the above answers API to grab all answers within a given time range. Then check if an answer's parent question has certain tags. But it doesn't look very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want to go **upvote [the feature request to add tag search for answers, etc](https://stackapps.com/questions/3279/please-add-the-tagged-parameter-to-answers-users-etc).** (If/when you have the upvote privilege)

In the meantime, **for answers by tag you can use [the `/search/excerpts` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search)** as long as you **include `is:answer` in the `q` parameter**.

For example:
      [/2.2/search/excerpts?&q=is:answer&tagged=best-in-place&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=is%3Aanswer&tagged=best-in-place&filter=!.FjwPGDVPxr%29v8rxGANw_yNo4_zj2&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

gets just answers whose questions are tagged with `best-in-place`.

---

**There is no workaround for comments.**  You can try repeatedly polling [the `/events` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events), but then you'd have to query each new event to find the tags.  It would get real messy, real quick.

---

**If you know the question IDs**, you can use [the `/questions/{ids}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) to fetch all of the answers and all of the comments under that question.

See, for example:
      [/2.2/questions/6567?site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=6567&filter=!OfYUQYtgCaZ7yj%28WahuQdxYywbkqzWg-jN8uMF.Naty&site=stackapps&run=true)

Be sure to set/use a filter that includes answers and comments.

Comment: Good to know /search/excerpts route can do the trick for answers. Thanks!