# wrong results of /search/advanced

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I am querying `mobile` in stackoverflow. The second result is an answer. Results of [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) is giving only questions when queried `mobile`. This is applicable for all other terms which are to be queried.

Comment: You need to provide **exact instructions** to duplicate this alleged bug.

Comment: @BrockAdams: [search_excerpt](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) will give the expected result. It can search answers also.

Comment: Note that I said as much in my first comment to the answer below.  One more reason why this is a poor question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search):

> Searches a site for any **questions** which fit the given criteria.

(emphasis mine)

The searches on the API aren't guaranteed to exactly replicate the current on-site search, so this behaviour is expected. This may change in some future release of the API, but the current behaviour is closer to the old on-site search approach, which only ever returned questions as top-level results.

Comment: The `/search` paths [can return answers too](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=foo&answers=1&tagged=mobile&filter=!*7Pa29%29f8*R4umycCObL9Yxm6Q0V&site=stackoverflow&run=true).  The question is poor and should be closed.

Comment: It's not really. They searched on the site and got an answer as the second result, they searched with the API and didn't, because the API doesn't return specific answers as results

Comment: If that's true -- and the OP was by no means clear on that point -- then the question should be closed as a duplicate of [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/4583/how-to-search-answers-like-isanswer), or [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/646/the-search-route-is-ignoring-the-answers-parameter), or [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/6593/search-for-answers-comments-under-questions-with-certain-tags-using-the-stack-ov), or one of about 4 other questions.

Comment: @BrockAdams the answers link given by you in the first comment is not not the required one.

Comment: @BrockAdams also other questions are related but do not answer this question. they help but do not answer.